# Gostaria de enviar os dados de um arquivo txt(lido) para uma listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Por exemplo:

Leitura do arquivo

```
string [] linhas = File.ReadAllLines("ip.txt");
Console.ReadLine();
```

fiz a leitura do arquivo, agora, quero jogar eles em uma `ListBox`, como fazer?

Comment: Você está usando Formulários?

Comment: sim. windows form, eu consegui ler um arquivo, agora quero enviar ele para a listbox

Comment: o que tem cada linha do arquivo txt?

Comment: IP's 200.135.80.9, vou tentar antes de enviar para listbox, validar se o ip é valido ou não

Comment: cada linha é um IP? como está formatado esse txt?

Comment: cada linha é um ip, existem ips validos e uns não, preciso validar e enviar pra listbox valida ou invalida por exemplo :                                                                                                                      
200.135.80.9
192.168.1.1
8.35.67.74
257.32.4.5
85.345.1.2
1.2.3.4
9.8.234.5
192.168.0.256

Comment: Você quer na pergunta uma coisa não tem validação, como está validando?

Comment: vou explicar detalhadamente, preciso ler o arquivo txt, validar se o ip é valido ou não, e enviar pra uma listbox :IPAddress ipAddr;
            string addr = " 200.135.80.9";

 

            bool res = IPAddress.TryParse(addr, out ipAddr);

 

            if (res)
                Console.WriteLine("ip valido");

 

 

            else
                Console.WriteLine(" ip Invalido");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente para ler um arquivo de texto onde cada linha represente um número `ip` e adicionar em um [ListBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=net-5.0) é simples:

```
using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader("ip.txt"))
{
    string item = string.Empty;
    while ((item = str.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out _))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

***Nota:*** a estrutura que está utilizando tem baixo desempenho e como vai precisar iterar em cada linha a melhor forma é essa, fazendo dentro da própria leitura a adição, economiza memória e aumenta desempenho.

Comment: cara, muito obrigado mesmo, deu certo o que pedi, você sabe alguma função que eu possa validar se o ip é valido ou não? são duas listbox, ip valido e ip invalido

Comment: @Matheusbatista fiz a alteração com a validação e o descarte onde só precisa do valor texto.

Comment: caraca, mano, muito obrigado mesmo, deu certinho... como posso te recompensar? nunca pensei que alguém conseguiria ajudar tanto assim.

Comment: @Matheusbatista só quando criar uma pergunta coloque todos os detalhes na própria pergunta e seja bem claro, quando você aceita a pergunta e clica na seta pra cima já está ajudando a comunidade.

Comment: Não não @Matheusbatista aqui é para ajudar mesmo ... fica tranquilo

Comment: Muito obrigado! c# não é a minha praia. mas outras linguagens, pode ter certeza que irei acompanhar o fórum e tentar ajudar o pessoal, acredito que isso seja a ideia do site.